# Export SSL session key in ubuntu

Tags: ssl, encryption, export, wireshark

I want to debug connection secured over ssl. I found that it possible to decrypt captured data with wireshark if session keys are available.
As described in manuals I tried to export keys and open browser with same terminal window.

```
export SSLKEYLOGFILE=~/Documents/ssl.log
firefox
```

However when I navigate to https connection, ssl.log file is not created. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ever tried a "simpler" path like `/tmp/ssl.log` ? Is another instance of firefox running already ?

Comment: Yep, just tried. No log file.

Comment: This site is about programming, not using a tool. Vote to close.

Comment: @Scolytus what appropriate site would be for this type of question?

Comment: @Scolytus this question makes sense to be here